# Is there an example of using fetch with flowjs?

Tags: javascript, types, fetch, flowtype

I'm trying to use fetch in my async function, but flow is throwing this error

Error:(51, 26) Flow: Promise. This type is incompatible with union: type application of identifier `Promise` | type parameter `T` of await

this is a code that can generate this error:

```
async myfunc() {
   const response = await fetch('example.com');
   return await response.json();
}
```

I would like to type the response of `response.json`

Comment: https://flow.org/try/#0IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLZkdACgEoYBvAKBiqkxGRgCcBTEAB1qZgF4ZgB3YKnpwmyKAAsCAciYAPYNlYAbJgDoa2KUQDclKs2QIGWfoPrM2HVQCsQmYroC+QA

Comment: I would like to type my response

Comment: tks, great code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may either annotate the return type of the function using `Promise <T>` where `T` is the desired type or assign the result to a temporary local with an explicit type annotation and then return that local. The function return type will then be inferred.

**Explicit return type annotation:**

```
async myfunc(): Promise<{name: string}> {
    const response = await fetch('example.com');
    return await response.json();
}
```

**Inferred return type from explicitly annotated local:**

```
async myfunc() {
    const response = await fetch('example.com');
    const result: {name: string} = await response.json();
    return result;
}
```